Are GUID-based fragment identifiers in Material Design documentation stable enough for long-term referencing?
We would like to use a link from our documentation to the Material Design documentation with a hyperlink containing a "fragment identifier," such as https://m3.material.io/components/top-app-bar/specs#e3fd3eba-0444-437c-9a82-071ef03d85b1
Are these GUIDs stable enough for us to reference them explicitly in our documentation, or should we avoid this approach since they might change during the documentation update process?
